# XPath selecting first node and second node when two have a similar name

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML document that looks like the following:

```
<foo>
  <a>...</a>
  <a>...</a>
  <b>...</b>
</foo>
```

When using `<xsl:value-of>`, how do I select the contents of the first `<a>` node and then perhaps the second `<a>` node as a bonus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
/foo/a[1]
```

or (bonus) :

```
/foo/a[2]
```